# TA Stochastic indicator calculation error: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: python, dataframe, technical-indicator

I try to calculate a stochastic indicator

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import ta    

highprices = pd.DataFrame([1111, 1112, 1114, 1116, 1118, 1119, 1130, 1140, 1160])
lowprices = pd.DataFrame([999, 1000, 1100, 1111, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1110])
lastprices = pd.DataFrame([1110, 1110, 1110, 1110, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111])
slowk = ta.momentum.stoch(highprices, lowprices, lastprices,  3,  1)
slowd = slowk.rolling(3).mean()
print(slowk, slowd)
sys.exit()
```

But it gives me

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try `print(ta.momentum.stoch.__doc__)` and you'll find that `high`, `low`, and `close` are supposed to be `pd.Series`, not `pd.DataFrame`. E.g. `high(pandas.Series): dataset 'High' column.` So, just change that for all three, and it should work.

Comment: Geez! Thanks! that was it. How is someone supposed to know lol! ta-lib wants arrays...